# What is the definition for second chance points in the NBA?

Tags: basketball, terminology, nba

I have been reading this, but the details still feel unclear.
https://www.sportingcharts.com/dictionary/nba/second-chance-points.aspx

**Short question:**
Will any shooting miss activate the possibility for second chance points as long as the ball stays on the team? (ie both regular shot and free throw). Or wont a missed free throw activate the possibility for second chance on the teams next shot?

The link says

> If a player is fouled on a shot attempt and receives free throws, any points scored are not considered second chance points.

[1] I interpret this that if a player tries to shoot, but is fouled, this will not count ass a missed shot that will activate the chance to get second chance points on an eventual free throw. Am i right?

Comment: I would interpret this as, any points scored after an offensive rebound.  This would include a free throw miss.

Comment: If you have a new question, ask it separately and link this for context. Old questions should not be edited to include follow-up or to change the original question.

Answer (score 1):

To quote the article from original link included in the OP:

> A basketball phrase used to describe any points scored during a possession by the offense after an offensive player has **already attempted one shot and missed.**

I take this as meaning that any shot attempt that allows for a rebound (which includes the last shot on a free throw sequence) that results in an offensive rebound and a subsequent score will be considered second chance points. So yes, getting an offensive rebound immediately activates a second chance point chance.

> If a player is fouled on a shot attempt and receives free throws, any
>   points scored are not considered second chance points.

My interpretation of this is that even if a player fouled on a shot attempt off an offensive rebound makes the shot for an and-one free throw, the points scored on that shot (but not on the free throw) would also be credited as second-chance points, much like how this would be counted as a field goal.

Answer (score -2):

Basketball is a game of offense and defense. The defense wins when the offense fails to score on a single possession. The offense can lose to the defense in a multitude of ways (Turnovers, Missed Shots, Offensive fouls). The offense can win in multiple ways besides making a basket(scoring). This is where second chance points come into play. When the offense is able to recover a missed shot (offensive rebound), they are rewarded with a second chance to score... if they do score the correct term for this is (second chance point).

Answer (score -3):

In simple sense. It's when points are scored when the ball is recovered and scored from within the same offensive play